# How to compare Harrell C-index from different models in survival analysis?

Tags: survival

In a dataset with survival event, I calculated Harrell C-index from three different models.
Furthermore, I calculated the 95% C.I. for the three different models.

So the next question is to compare the discrimination ability of the three models.

Could anyone kindly suggest the method to compare the Harrell C-index?

Answer (score 5):

Harrell would advise that you NOT do so:

[How to do ROC-analysis in R with a Cox model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17480/how-to-do-roc-analysis-in-r-with-a-cox-model/17517#17517)

Doing model comparison with LR statistics is more powerful than using methods that depend on an asymptotic distribution of the *C-index*.

Comment: Thanks DWin. Actually I have performed LR test to test the predictive adequacy index of the 3 model (vs. combined). The confusing point is I found the model with the highest C-index but have moderate adequacy index.

Comment: Or another alternative is: using bootstrap, I calculate the 3 C-index in every resampled population. Thus, I get the 95% CI of the C-index of the differences between model A/B/C. The one with 95% CI >0 is the "significant" better?

Answer (score 0):

LR statistics are well suited for hierarchical models. In case of various variables in models I guess information criteria (Akaike - AIC or Bayes BIC) will answer which model is the best.