# How does length of follow-up affect hazard ratio (prop hazards vs non-prop hazards)

Tags: survival, cox-model, hazard, proportional-hazards

As the title says, I'm trying to figure out how the length of follow-up affects the value of the hazard ratio (e.g. from a Cox model). If proportional hazard holds, then presumably the hazard ratio point estimate should be identical regardless of whether we truncate followup at 1 year, 2 year etc. If it does not hold and the hazard ratio is time varying, only then should the length of follow-up affect the value of the hazard ratio. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues to disentangle.

First, if proportional hazards (PH) strictly hold, then the *expected value* of the log-hazard ratio (model coefficient) should be independent of the duration of observations. But the precision of the estimate will depend on the number of events. If you have a shorter duration of observations, you will have less precision and might end up with sample-based point estimates that differ depending on that duration. In general, the more events you have the better.

Second, a lack of PH might not necessarily lead to differences in estimated hazard ratios over different durations of observations, depending on the details of the deviation from PH. As @AdamO explains on [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/341114/28500), if PH is violated than you get a sort of event-averaged hazard ratio from a Cox model. Depending on the pattern of deviations from PH, two particular choices of observation durations could (in principle) thus lead to similar event-averaged hazard ratios.

Also, note that perfect adherence to the PH assumption is unlikely. You have to evaluate whether any violation of PH is big enough to matter in practice.

A final warning about terminology: in survival analysis the word "truncated" has a particular meaning. It refers to event times that could not have been observed, given the study design.

So it's risky to say that you "truncate followup at 1 year, 2 year etc." That's correct English usage, but it can lead to some confusion. The individuals still event-free after you "truncate followup" have *right-censored* event times. It's safer to say something like "stop follow-up." See [Klein and Moeschberger](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387953991), or [many pages on this site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsurvival%5D+truncat*+censor*), for the distinction between truncation and censoring in survival analysis.